# Issue with SQL create table error in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, create-table

Can someone help me find the reason this SQL query isn't working in Microsoft SQL Server?

```
CREATE TABLE USER 
(
     USER_ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
     USER_L_NAME varchar(30) NOT NULL,
     USER_F_NAME varchar(20) NOT NULL,
     PASSWORD varchar(20) NOT NULL,
     USERNAME varchar(20) NOT NULL,
     DOB date NOT NULL,
     COUNTRY char(30) NOT NULL,
     STATE_REGION char(2),
     EMAIL varchar(20) NOT NULL,
     STREET varchar(50) NOT NULL,
     CITY varchar(30),
     ZIP_CODE char(5),
     MOBILE_PHONE char(11)
);
```

Comment: What does it means "isn't working"? What error are you getting?

Comment: @Alejandro general syntax error

Comment: @JustinLowenstein When you report an error, please don't paraphrase.  Cut & paste the entire message.

Comment: We should NEVER store plain-text passwords in a database.

Answer (score 7):

`USER` is [a reserved word in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) - as in most other databases.

You can either quote this identifier by surrounding it with square brackets (`CREATE TABLE [USER] (...)`), or change the table name to something else - such as `USERS` for example.

I would recommend the latter. Using reserved words for identifiers is error-prone (you need to quote the identifier *everywhere* you use it later on), and can easily be avoided.